# Is an Underscore template safe from cross-site scripting when it's retrieved from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, underscore.js, xss, sanitization

I'd like to embed an Underscore template in my HTML in a `script` tag, like

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-share">
// Template markup
</script>
```

I'm working in WordPress, so I'm planning on loading this template with the `wp.template` utility function. This looks for a node with the given ID in the DOM, grabs the contents with a jQuery `html()` call, and passes them to `_.template` to prepare it ready to be populated with data.

I'm including all the parameters in my template in `{{ }}` tags, so the values will be escaped.

But my question's about the template, not the params. Can I trust a template string extracted from the DOM with JS like this? Can I be reasonably confident nobody can modify that string for an XSS attack? Or should I sanitise it using something like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) before passing it to Underscore[1](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)?

Comment: It's as immune as any of your other page assets (like other `<script>` blocks), to the extent that any externally-sourced content in it has been appropriately escaped.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, you mean if an attacker can interfere with the template that means they can already interfere with practically anything on the page?